# How can I pass a text to an external program without changing the current buffer?

Tags: external-command

I want to do filter through an external program without actually filtering the lines (but to keep them). For example :

```
%!grep aa > newfile
```

If I do this, all the lines are deleted and I need to do undo

There is a more neat way to run an external program with args without changing the current buffer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you’re looking for `:help :write_c`. Try this:

```
:w !grep aa > newfile
```

Answer (score 3):

@Rich answered your question very well. However, judging by your example you may want to look into `:vimgrep`/`:grep`.

```
:vimgrep /pat/ %
:grep 'pat' %
```

Both `:vimgrep` & `:grep` will put the results into the quickfix list. Here are a few quickfix list commands to get you up and running fast:

- Use `:cnext` and `:cprev` to move between your errors/matches. I suggest you [map these commands](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired).
- `:cfirst` and `:clast` to go to the first and last error/matches respectively.
- `:copen` to open up the quickfix list in a window (`:cclose` to close)
- `:cwindow` to open quickfix list window only if there are errors
- `:cc` to display the current error/match.
- Use `:cdo {cmd}` to run a command, `{cmd}` on each quickfix entry.
- You can use `%` on the command-line to supply the current filename.

Vimcast episodes:

See the following [Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) episode:

- [Project-wide find and replace](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/project-wide-find-and-replace/) Note: `:cdo` is available in Vim 8.
- [Search multiple files with :vimgrep](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/search-multiple-files-with-vimgrep/)

For more help see the following:

```
:h quickfix
:h :cnext
:h :cfirst
:h :cope
:h :cwindow
:h :cc
:h :cdo
:h :_%
```

Comment: Thanks. It is just an example. But helpful answer. +1 for vimcasts :)